# AS3: If Else Condition not working/always false

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

Good Day!.

I was trying to do something If ELSE Condition in AS3. But when I try to run it, its always proceed to the ELSE instead of IF. The condition is true but its still proceed in ELSE.. I just copied it to another function and all of them working but this one function its not working.

Here's my code:

```
 mcRoomName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, roomName)
    function roomName(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        trim(mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text);
        trace(mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text);
        if(mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text == "Room")
        {
            trace("correct");
        }
        else
        {
                trace("wrong");
        }
    }
```

I also tried to copy and paste the word "Room" in the code and paste it to textbox still not working...

Below is the print screen of my textbox...Its a movieclip and inside it is the textbox... The name of movieclip is "mcRoomName" then the name of textbox is "txtRoomName".

Codes for my Trim:

```
function trim( s:String ):String
{
  return s.replace(/^[\s|\t|\n]+|[\s|\t|\n]+$/gs, '');
}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Did you debug and see what is the value of `mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text` !!!

Comment: @TheNewIdiot..  yes.the value is still the same...

Comment: May be you need to trim the `mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text` value and then compare.

Comment: try to do it : `trace(mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text , (mcRoomName.txtRoomName.text == "Room" ));` what do you see?

Comment: @TheNewIdiot..I edit my post and tried the trim but its still not working.. :(

Comment: @Cherniv...Already tried what you said...The output is false...

Comment: 1. Is this the exact same code you have in your app because I see not reasons why you should always have false.  2. Are you sure you do not have somehow a ; after the if condition ? :D

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu..Q#1, The code above is the same in my codes, 100% the same...then Q#2. Yes, I don't have any " ; " after the if condition.....Its weird that is always false..

Comment: And all `.as` files are saved? in Flash IDE there is no auto-save

Comment: @Cherniv..Yes..I already tried to create a new file and copy paste the code there.. but still its always false...so weird...

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima please try the following `trace(mcRoomName.txtRoomName)`, let me know what's the output

Comment: @Teejay...the output is "Room"

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima Ok we found the culprit. You used the name `txtRoomName` as the text variable.  So just use `if(mcRoomName.txtRoomName == "Room")`

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima Also note that your `Trim` function is completely useless, since you are returning a string and you're not using it! You should write `mcRoomName.txtRoomName = trim(mcRoomName.txtRoomName);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out..But still its so weird..

I changed the "behavior" of my textbox from "Multi line" to "Single line", and its works.

But the others textbox are "Multi line" and the code are the same from the above I post.

And thanks for the help... I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Teejay...Just finished to check your code but its not working...When I add the ".text" after the txtRoomName it works.. Thanks for the help! :)